# Display image on JFrame form Java NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I want to show a image on top this form, but I don't know how. I have tried many times, but I cant find any image container in Toolbox.

Screenshot of JFrame:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECVNl.png]

Comment: post the code you tried

Comment: i have search for any pictureBox or image container and i cant find that is toolBox

Comment: Looked like `JPanel` to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i cant find any image container I

Add an `ImageIcon` to a `JLabel`.

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(...);
JLabel label = new JLabel( icon );
frame.add( label );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for a working example.